# Eclipse EGit, working with forked project. Getting updates from the original project

Tags: eclipse, git, github, windows-7, egit

Hello everybody I have this "big" and frustrating problem,

I have forked a project from git and as usual it is available in my account in GitHub. I then set up a project in eclipse selecting from an existing URI. All is ok, if I work with my own version of the project.

What I want to do is, because the project is changing and growing day by day, to have an updated copy from the original project and, every time I want to download any change I would like that the download is from the original project.

At the moment the only way (with EXTREMELY big problems) I found is using "Team > Fetch from Upstream" the changing the link to the repos using the "config" button. Obviously this lead to conflicts and annoying problems. I am sure that this is not the correct way to handle a forked repos and I need help.

I am using windows 7 and eclipse with egit, if I press Windows-R and then cmd it don't recognize the command "git" so I can't use console commands.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With windows 7, you can install git to your machine and use console command as normal. ([Link to download](http://git-scm.com/download/win))
2. See [this link](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) to configure git to sync your fork with the original repo.

Hope this can help.